# priority based update of file data and multithreading in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, fileparsing

i wan't to modify a file using multiple threads at any given time given the constraints that

- each thread has a priority either normal or max.
- file contains a table (let say marks of students(name,roll no.) in a particular subject).
- any line which can be modified by a normal priority thread can be later modified by any thread.
- once a line is modified by a max priority thread , the normal priority threads can't modify that particular line .

scheduling a threads to access file is doable but restricting some line from being modified by some threads is quite difficult for me .
how can i accomplish above task in java ?
please answer my question considering i'm very new to java , multithreading/concurrent programming and file parsing in java .
thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds like something you would use a database for.

Comment: This feels a bit too broad for this site, as it is really asking for a tutorial on Java concurrency. There are plenty of resources you can find that will answer how to manage concurrent access to a file. Your best bet is to implement some code to test these ideas and come back when you have a specific question about that code.

Comment: i don't want the whole solution but a way to ensure selective access by different threads but i think my question was not accurate , let me ask this there's is a black box it contains several tooth brush , let us assume that a whole family has this weird trend of sharing brushes hence no one has a particular brush but there's a "guy" whose used brushes are nightmares for others so they want to avoid using those brushes which are used by the "guy" . any one can pick any brush any time. 
any idea how to save the other members in the family.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding the design can be:

```
class ToothBrushHolder{
   List<ToothBrush> toothBrushList;
   ToothBrush pickToothBrush{
        ToothBrush:pick the tooth brush from list
         }
   void useToothBrush(ToothBrush toothBrush){
        synchronize(toothBrush){
        if(toothBrush.getLastUsedBy!= "particularThreadName"){
          //perform the action
           toothBrush.setLastUsedBy("ThreadName);
      }else
        { can't use brush
           }
 }
 }

class ToothBrush{
    String ToothBrushID;
    String LastUsedBy;//setThreadname
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

Correctly controlling concurrent modification of specific lines in a file may be particularly difficult, given that you're new to concurrency in Java.

If the file is not too large, it might be easier to read it into a standard data structure (see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) that provides guaranteed atomic operations, or to create your own data structure and implement a synchronized method for updating that data structure.

Comment: thanks for the link sir but i need an approach . you said it is difficult to ensure modification of specific line can you try to explain the difficult way once i will try my level best to understand that and also it will be better than reading whole documentation .